# Where does windows 7 put files in emergency

Tags: windows-7, crash

When windows 7 unexpectantly crashes where would windows put files that were not saved?

Thanks.

Comment: What files are you looking for?  Application files?  If so, what app(s)

Comment: or document if so what type of doc?

Comment: I am looking for staruml files. The extension is .uml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't put them anywhere. Mainly because Windows probably doesn't know which parts of an applications memory represent unsaved files. Windows probably doesn't expect unexpected crashes.

Specific applications may store none, some or all of your unsaved work in temporary files. It depends on the application.